# Relatively positioned elements in scrollable absolutely positioned div "lag behind" on scroll

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, mobile

I have a PhoneGap app that displays a quite long text with headers, tables and images which I am testing on Android.

Everything works fine except for the elements with style `position:relative`
These elements "lag" behind when scrolling, meaning if I scroll the page then those elements start and end scrolling about a quarter of a second later.

The bug happens when combining an absolute div with relative children and a child with `overflow:auto`. Removing any of those things fixes the bug but I'd prefer do leave it in. Although I'd be willing to remove the table and show it separately (like in a dialog) if I have to.

The bug only presents on the standard Android Browser (and of course my PhoneGap app).
So far I've tested it with the following devices:

> - Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.1.1)
> - Samsung Galaxy S III (4.1.2)

Any help is appreciated but I'd prefer a solution where the HTML and functionality are not changed (or not too much).

[image: after quick scrolling]

I created a [minimal example](http://www.pnn.ch/temp/android-browser-bug.html) showing the bug. Simply open it on your Android and start scrolling and you should see the problem immediately:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"></head>
<body style="margin:0">

<div style="position:absolute;overflow:auto;top:100px;bottom:100px;width:100%">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a quam arcu. Duis ultrices mollis nibh ut hendrerit. Etiam a interdum metus. Integer volutpat, nibh laoreet euismod suscipit, libero sem iaculis lorem, ut hendrerit magna orci eu elit. Nulla eu ultricies libero. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas nec turpis vitae magna lobortis ornare sit amet ut lacus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc vestibulum lobortis orci, sit amet ornare dui congue nec. Morbi id magna at turpis auctor ultricies. Ut rhoncus quam augue, ut consectetur risus.</p>
  <div style="position:relative;background:red;">relative box<br>moves slower than the other text</div>
  <p>Fusce congue orci a nunc gravida sed pretium lorem convallis. Etiam hendrerit, ligula eget lobortis vestibulum, arcu sapien pharetra magna, auctor suscipit nisl tellus quis lacus. Cras id elit at ante mollis venenatis. Donec eu sollicitudin odio. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras et tortor sed mi faucibus sagittis non quis metus. Morbi mauris ante, posuere vel rutrum id, mattis id enim. Morbi purus quam, euismod facilisis blandit quis, commodo at justo. Aliquam in fermentum nibh. Curabitur pharetra blandit risus sit amet tristique. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur interdum eleifend justo, et dapibus justo volutpat sed.</p>          
  <div style="overflow:auto">
    <table>
      <tr><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th></tr>
      <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please provide a jsfiddle or a tinkerbin or liveweave

Comment: I updated the post with a link. Those services unfortunately don't let you add meta headers.

Comment: Any chance this is fixed by forcing hardware acceleration? I stopped using phone gap because I had scrolling issues, but I "fixed" them by adding a translate3d with a 0 value which usually fixed things visually. Does this help you?

Comment: +Leeish Thanks for the tip. That's the solution I'm going with.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In short, the ills you are suffering are common and documented.  Elements with `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll` suffer from paint/reflow/render issues in both desktop and mobile browsers.  To compound upon that there are issues in mobile browsers (webkit both on iOS and Android) with regards to not rendering relative and absolute elements if they are "off screen".  This can lead to a lag when they are scrolled on screen.

There are a few "hack" shims that you can apply:

```
element {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

element > * {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}

element > * {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Some reading for you:

- http://cantina.co/2012/03/06/ios-5-native-scrolling-grins-and-gothcas/
  http://developersday.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/scrollable-divs-rendering-issues-with-css-overflow-auto-or-scroll-iosandroid/

And a snippet I copied from somewhere into my notes and now can't find the source:

> Especially on sites that rely heavily on scroll, you might discover
>   that your main content is relying on overflow:scroll. This is a real
>   challenge as this scrolling isn’t GPU accelerated in any way so the
>   content is repainted whenever your user scrolls. You can work around
>   such issues using normal page scroll (overflow:visible) and
>   position:fixed.

Comment: Thanks! BTW The quote is from http://addyosmani.com/blog/devtools-visually-re-engineering-css-for-faster-paint-times/

Comment: The last two CSS snippets work. I feel so stupid because I read about these before but somehow didn't realize they had to apply to the children of the scrolling element :D 
Does it matter which one I use concerning performance and support? Is it advisable to use it even when there's no problem? I have concerns that it'll slow down the render especially if there's lots of elements.

Comment: @Thomas - thanks for finding the quote... Addy is an amazing web activist and you should read his ebook on Javascript design patterns if you haven't already.

Comment: @Thomas - I haven't run really heavy performance testing on these and less so on device emulators (desktop guy here)... but, forcing the GPU acceleration on elements (which is what those last two tricks do) so that they will render off visible screen and thus be snappier, is of course a trade off.  

I wouldn't use it on a very long list, but then again on a long list I would recommend an infinite scrolling implementation where you re-use a set of elements.

TLDR; - you are forcing it to render and GPU accelerate all those elements... so yeah, caution.  Also CSS with * is inherently horrific.

Comment: Is the bug filed somewhere?

Comment: @mivaas19 No, I didn't. Where should it be filed anyway? It only happens in the default Android browser and not in any other WebKit browsers.

Comment: Informative answer thanks Nick, is your answer suggesting using one of those hacks, or a combination of them?

Comment: Many thanks!! I'm building an app using Phonegap and on android devices the elements from a list page where disappearing while scrolling and now it's fixed! iOS wasn't causing me problems with scrolling.
@MattyJ I'm only using translateZ and works great, no need for the rest. :)

Comment: I was also working on phonegap android the elements are still lagy  I know the problem is because i have updating images .do i get any  suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two issues you're trying to fix. The text that slips down below and the lagging scroll speed?

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the copyright symbol but I wouldn't have a `line-height` less than `1` or `1em`. Try to use a parent element and style the span off of that. You can probably use `display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;` on the span to get the desired effect.

```
<p><span>&copy;</span>Some text</p>
```

For scrolling it depends on what you're doing. Mobile browsers wait `300ms` for `<a>` tags to see if you are scrolling or clicking a link. It could be related to that. If so, I'd checkout `Google FastClick`.

Mobile browsers accelerate page scrolling on the body. So using nested divs or `position:absolute` could keep you from getting the faster scroll speed. In newer versions of `Android` and `iOS` you can use -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch to help but that won't do anything for older phones. I would try not to use position absolute because based on your example it doesn't look like its required, also using nested divs that scroll require some users to use two fingers inside the div to scroll content. I would try to avoid that as well and replace the design with more mobile friendly design patterns like a link that expands content down.

A lot of the scrolling issues have came to light while trying to support `position:fixed` on mobile if think that might be causing it and you'd like to read about it: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: I just have a problem with certain elements (postion:relative) having a different scroll lag so when you scroll it looks a bit like paralax scrolling. It's hard to explain so I've added a screenshot.
For the copyright symbols I copied some CSS from our website where we had a problem with some browsers not correctly rendering super- and subscript when in a table cell with vertical-align:top.

Comment: The outermost div is the content area of my app. It's absolutely positioned to leave space for the header and footer. Or is there a better way?
The bug actually disappears when I remove the table so the horizontal overflow seems to be the problem.

Comment: don't use position absolute. if its only for mobile stack a header, content div, and footer on top of each other with 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute` and `position:relative` , they are absolutely NOT needed for this layout and are causing all your problems.

You can add some `margin-top` to your body if you wish.

`PhoneGap` produces some html garbage like that, I hope that you have a fine control of the CSS.

Comment: The posted code is only a minimal example. I need the absolute positioning because I need animations and I also need to show the content in a dialog. And I need relative positioning to position the children absolutely. In short I need it to duplicate some design elements of our website.
And what PhoneGap html garbage do you mean? It's all my garbage :D

Comment: Position:relative and position:absolute are known to cause problems in mobile browsers - and support may vary a lot. Do you know how to do remote Web Develop inspection? That's how you can play with your CSS and see what works or not. Here's how: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging Once you set this up you're king. Do you know how to use the Dev Tools?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remove those. Especially if the outer div is a dialog which has to be absolute.
Yes I know how to use the DevTools but I've never done it remotely. The method in the link you provided unfortunately only works for Chrome (where it's working fine). But I've tested it inside the packaged app with the debug feature of PhoneGap Build. It's using [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) which I'll have a look at.

Comment: The link you sent is Chrome-only as it's a feature of the **Chrome** Developer Tools. Unfortunately I've been trying stuff for hours without success...

Comment: Actually, an absolute positioned box is placed related to a RELATIVELY positioned box, so try inversing position:absolute with position:relative in these two divs and see what happens. As it is know it can be that the relative box doesn't know how/where to be placed (or takes the body..)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a simple CSS fix for it, adding `position:relative` to your paragraphs solve the problem.

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
p{ position:relative;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">

<div style="position:absolute;overflow:auto;top:100px;bottom:100px;width:100%">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a quam arcu. Duis ultrices mollis nibh ut hendrerit. Etiam a interdum metus. Integer volutpat, nibh laoreet euismod suscipit, libero sem iaculis lorem, ut hendrerit magna orci eu elit. Nulla eu ultricies libero. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas nec turpis vitae magna lobortis ornare sit amet ut lacus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc vestibulum lobortis orci, sit amet ornare dui congue nec. Morbi id magna at turpis auctor ultricies. Ut rhoncus quam augue, ut consectetur risus.</p>
  <div style="position:relative;background:red;">relative box<br>moves slower than the other text</div>
  <p>Fusce congue orci a nunc gravida sed pretium lorem convallis. Etiam hendrerit, ligula eget lobortis vestibulum, arcu sapien pharetra magna, auctor suscipit nisl tellus quis lacus. Cras id elit at ante mollis venenatis. Donec eu sollicitudin odio. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras et tortor sed mi faucibus sagittis non quis metus. Morbi mauris ante, posuere vel rutrum id, mattis id enim. Morbi purus quam, euismod facilisis blandit quis, commodo at justo. Aliquam in fermentum nibh. Curabitur pharetra blandit risus sit amet tristique. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur interdum eleifend justo, et dapibus justo volutpat sed.</p>          
  <div style="overflow:auto">
    <table>
      <tr><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th>    <th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th>    <th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th></tr>
      <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>    <td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td>    <td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That seems to work at first but the table and some other elements are still laging. Even if I apply it to `#topdiv > *` the table is still laging. Perhaps there is a solution but I'll go with the transform solution